# Web Forms for Marketers Form Report Export into PDF in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

am working with "Web Forms for Marketers Form",in this section I need to export the reports, am able to see only two options(Excel,XML) in top right of the screen.

[image]

Is there any chance to add the custom report like PDF in sitecore 8.1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar answer as to another your question: yes, it is possible. But it will require development. Try to read more about Sitecore SPEAK framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding custom button or as suggested by Anton you can achieve the requirement through SPEAK Framework. Below are some links that would be useful for you.

https://jeffreyrondeau.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/extending-web-forms-for-marketers-form-report-export/

https://sitecoretweaks.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/sitecore-export-to-csvexcel-of-web-form-for-marketers-form-wffm-reports/

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/05/10/export-to-csv-in-the-form-reports-of-sitecores-web-forms-for-marketers/